# prevent facebook js sdk from calling login callback

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Facebook login button:

```
<fb:login-button scope="email,user_birthday">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

and this JS:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'APP_ID_HERE',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
};
```

My issue is that any page that contains this code always reloads once. It's because the `login` callback above is called (if the user is logged in to a Facebook account) even if the user has not yet clicked on the Login button above. Is this normal behavior? If not, how do I prevent the `login` callback from being called?

Comment: it is correct. the callback is invoke when user has login fb in another tab without button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This event fires each time the SDK detects that the state changes from unknown/not_connected to connected.

It sounds like you want to actually provide a callback handler on the login button via `onlogin`

Answer (score 0):

One solution: You could use the PHP sdk to check for the user status, and only if the user is NOT logged in, create the JavaScript part where you subscribe to `auth.login`.